# php rename adds double quotes around file name

Tags: php, image, rename, jpeg, double-quotes

I'm trying to rename some jpegs in a single directory. The code half works in that they are renamed with the correct filenames but for some reason the new filenames are surrounded with double quotes which makes them inaccessible from my web pages.

Any help appreciated!

```
$i = 10000;

foreach ($imgArray as $v) {

    $html_file_name = basename($v).PHP_EOL;
    $html_file_name =  str_replace(range(0,9),'', $html_file_name);

    $path = pathinfo($v, PATHINFO_DIRNAME);

    $target = ++$i . $html_file_name;

    rename ($v, $path . '/' . $target);

}
```

OK so here's the var_dump($imgArray):

```
array(3) { [0]=> string(47) "../img/gallery/this-is-the-first/10002-vddf.jpg" [1]=> string(51) "../img/gallery/this-is-the-first/10001-vfdssddf.jpg" [2]=> string(50) "../img/gallery/this-is-the-first/10003-vddsvsf.jpg" }
```

Serialized:

```
a:3:{i:0;s:47:"../img/gallery/this-is-the-first/10002-vddf.jpg";i:1;s:51:"../img/gallery/this-is-the-first/10001-vfdssddf.jpg";i:2;s:50:"../img/gallery/this-is-the-first/10003-vddsvsf.jpg";}
```

Comment: i gues u could use str.replace('"','\'', $string);

Comment: Your code does not contain the cause for that phenomenon.

Comment: I thought about that but I was wondering why it is doing the double quotes in the first place, if I new why the maybe I could implement a nicer solution

Comment: @PeeLee: The string `$html_file_name` is likely to contain such quotes. So you either need to remove them or even better, don't put them in there in the first place. Improve your HTML parsing. http://php.net/strings

Comment: What does `$imgArray` look like  .. ??

Comment: @phant0m, that's pretty much all the code... hmm

Comment: You need to look at `$imgArray`.

Comment: @hakre $html_file_name looks like:../img/gallery/this-is-the-first/10001-vfdssddf.jpg

Comment: @Baba $imgArray looks like:Array ( [0] => ../img/gallery/this-is-the-first/10002-vddf.jpg [1] => ../img/gallery/this-is-the-first/10001-vfdssddf.jpg [2] => ../img/gallery/this-is-the-first/10003-vddsvsf.jpg )

Comment: can you `serialize($imgArray)` and put it here .. i would like to test your array myself

Comment: @PeeLee: Use `var_dump` instead of `print_r`. Also don't post that in comments, but edit your question. Apart from that your code looks horrorful. I bet you make a lot of mistakes in other places, too. So better do some early error checking and proper debugging to be on the safe side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have new line issue in file name

```
  $html_file_name = basename($v).PHP_EOL;
                                    ^-------- Appending End of Line to File Name
```

All you need is

```
$i = 10000;
foreach ($imgArray as $v) {
    rename($v, pathinfo($v, PATHINFO_DIRNAME) . '/' . (++$i . str_replace(range(0,9),'',  basename($v))));
}
```

Comment: That was the culprit.  Thanks Baba

Comment: You are welcome @Pee Lee